# Custom Themes and Icons

Tags: feature-request, design

Many SE sites have custom backgrounds, badge icons and fonts. Also, would we change the PA.SE icon logo?

###### e.g. [CS.SE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/), [ELL.SE](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) and [Cooking.SE](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/).

###### Would we get one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not any time soon sadly. For one, the site is still in Public Beta and the [latest criteria](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/374096/congratulations-to-the-59-sites-that-just-left-beta) say that (among other requirements) a site can't graduate until it has been in Public Beta for at least 6 months.

About 7 years ago, getting a site design [was separated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263905/design-independent-graduation-is-on-for-early-september) from the process of graduating. This was laid out in [more detail](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303727/lets-break-up-with-graduation-and-remove-a-bunch-of-beta-labels) 4 years ago, where it was made apparent that a site design would be the last stage of a tiered site promotion and that many sites would likely never reach the activity levels deemed necessary to reach this step. As of 2019, there were at least [8 sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/324421/what-is-the-state-of-the-new-site-designs-promised-after-the-redesign#326798) that were pending receiving designs and have not yet. As of 4 years ago, SE has been trying to [reduce the number of unique themed elements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307862/ch-ch-ch-changes-left-nav-responsive-design-themes) any site has.

Taking all of that together, I would say site theme-ing is low on SE's priority list and, as the newest site on the network, Proof Assistants is probably at the back of the line for any design changes they plan to make.

Answer (score 6):

A different set of links which partially echoes [Tyberius' answer](https://proofassistants.meta.stackexchange.com/a/172/516) and provides additional information:

People have asked for [customization for beta sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56214/282094) long ago; recently, getting [customization for graduated sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369555/282094) poses some challenges and is slow going.

A realistic possibility is that we could get a customized design if this site is chosen by staff and a customer for sponsorship.

News (May 20, 2022): There's a bit of [movement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/378888/with-new-designs-planned-for-some-sites-are-there-plans-to-tackle-the-backlog#comment1264559_378888) on the question: "[What is the state of the new site designs promised after the redesign?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/326798/282094)". We aren't on the list, but we could ask.

[Courtesy](https://proofassistants.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171/custom-themes-and-icons/173?noredirect=1#comment441_173) of @[MartinSleziak](https://proofassistants.meta.stackexchange.com/users/106/martin-sleziak),  @[Catija](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/284336/catija)'s [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/378976/282094): :

> "[With new designs planned for some sites, are there plans to tackle the backlog?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/378976/282094)"

The [Stack Overflow Blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/07/11/stack-exchange-sites-are-getting-prettier-faster-introducing-themes/?cb=1&_ga=2.107920258.1490178802.1657597464-716306467.1634982377), July 11 2022, has an update on tackling the backlog of site theming:

> "Catija, our CM rep for the project, was excited to join the effort and helped make our backlog less intimidating. She did this by prioritizing the sites that still needed themes using the following factors: time since leaving beta, question volume, answer volume, total site users, daily visits, and questions per day. It was a great method because the sites waiting the longest also happened to be the sites near the top of her prioritization list.".

[Simon](https://datascience.meta.stackexchange.com/users/135721/laserbeamer)'s post "[Site design and logo — Draft](https://datascience.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2626/58034)" over at our Data Science site shows what resulted from their "[Custom Data Science design and logo - Information gathering](https://datascience.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2595/58034)" post, which describes the current process.